# How to enable CMIS on Documentum

Tags: cmis, documentum

I want to use [CmisSync](http://cmissync.com/documentum/) to synchronize [Documentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentum) folders/documents, so I must enable [CMIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) (Content Management Interoperability Services) in Documentum.

- The [Installation Notes](http://developer-downloads.emc.com/akdlm/ReadMe_HowToUseImage.txt?auth_code=1412690446_277432323d1531593d882142be0e2651&fileExt=.txt) and Readme don't even mention CMIS.
- It does not seem to be enabled by default, as the [CMIS URL](https://github.com/aegif/CmisSync/wiki/What-address) `http://localhost:8080/cmis/resources/` returns error 404 even though the REST URL is working correctly.

**QUESTION:** How to do enable CMIS in Documentum?

Environment:

- [Documentum Developer Edition 7.1](https://developer-content.emc.com/downloads/dctm_dev_edition_process.htm?product=dcm_dev) (I am not an EMC paying customer, so I use that because it is the only version which is freely downloadable)
- CentOS/Postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to find `emc-cmis.war`.

Once you have it, put it in the web application server that already contains your `dctm-rest.war` (present by default), and put `emc-cmis.war` besides it.

Tomcat (for instance) will automatically extract it into an `emc-cmis` folder besides the WAR. In my limited experience I have seen a case where the `emc-cmis` folder contained another `emc-cmis` folder that contains `WEB-INF`/etc, in such a case remove the extra level.

Within the `emc-cmis` folder, there should be a `dfc.properties` that you will need to modify, here is an example:

```
dfc.data.dir=/home/dmadmin/dctm/product/7.1/dfc_shared
dfc.tokenstorage.dir=/home/dmadmin/dctm/product/7.1/dfc_shared/apptoken
dfc.tokenstorage.enable=false
dfc.docbroker.host[0]=demo-server
dfc.docbroker.port[0]=1489
dfc.session.secure_connect_default=try_native_first
dfc.globalregistry.repository=MyRepo
dfc.globalregistry.username=dm_bof_registry
dfc.globalregistry.password=password
```

Any Documentum server contains a lot of `dfc.properties` that you can get inspiration from.

Then restart Tomcat, or the whole Documentum, and open http://localhost:8080/emc-cmis/main , this page should show up:

[image: EMC Documentum 7 CMIS REST Web Service]

The URLs are:

- REST: http://localhost:8080/emc-cmis/resources/
- Web Services: http://localhost:8080/emc-cmis/services/RepositoryService?wsdl

More information: https://www.emc.com/collateral/TechnicalDocument/docu57844.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check if you can access the CMIS installer in subscribenet. For development purposes you can download the CMIS war from the trial section in subscribenet and deploy it on the VM.

#### How To Find The CMIS war File

Navigate to Documentum download center and select "Content Server" to download, you will get a list of resources to download where CMIS.war is included.

#### Have A Look Here Too About CMISSync

- https://community.emc.com/message/825802#825802

Sources

- https://community.emc.com/people/Julien.Fontaine/blog/2013/06/11/cmis--does-it-work-and-how
- https://community.emc.com/thread/162817?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am not a paying customer, so I can't access subscribenet unfortunately. As you point out, the war is in the "*trial section* in subscribenet", and it is very unfortunate that the whole subscribenet is inaccessible to non-paying customers. If you find emc-cmis.war somewhere I would be very glad to get a download link!

Comment: Try here => https://chemistry.apache.org/java/download.html ... and maybe here too => http://seadva-test.d2i.indiana.edu:8081/artifactory/remote-repos/org/modeshape/modeshape-web-cmis-war/ ... Notice the title of the pages.

Comment: The binaries at the two links in your comment above are for unrelated products, not Documentum.